# Has anyone used SlickGrid with the updated drag functions jquery.event.drag-2.2.js?

Tags: drag-and-drop, slickgrid

I read from the [threedubmedia site](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag#) "The previous version of this plugin allowed this method to be overloaded with arguments to additionally bind handlers for "dragstart" and "dragend" in a single call, but this is no longer supported." but since I haven't actually read every line of the code I was wondering if this has already been accounted for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I upgraded to v2.2 (Updated: 2012-05-21) and it works fine for me. 
I actually had an issue with 'dragend' event getting missed sometimes with v2.0.
I was doing some operations at the end of 'dragend' event (like when user stops resizing column width), but sometimes the operation won't trigger because this event was missed. Actually one had to resize rather quickly and release mouse soon to get the problem in v2.0.

After upgrading to v2.2 those issues are gone.

Comment: FYI - SlickGrid core on github now uses v2.2 https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/26d96e994524d38ef57a76edee301277180761c6